# How can I create a static route between subnets on sonicwall

Tags: routing, subnet, sonicwall

I have a SonicWall and two Wifi Access Points (APs) connected to it.
The secured WLAN AP is connected to port X0 with subnet 192.168.22.x and has our "Secure" clients, as well as a printer.
The guest WLAN AP is connected to port X3 with subnet 192.168.77.x and is for visitors.

I'd like visitors to be able to use our printer but not see any of the other computers on the 22.x subnet.

How do I allow any user on the guest WLAN to access the printer at 192.168.22.123?

I have tried many things including turning off the firewall completely and putting both X0 and X3 in the same "Zone" (LAN).  Still, unable to communicate between 22.x and 77.x  The SonicWall is running SonicOS 6.

Thanks!

In theory, the Sonicwall should be able to do this

I tried to ad

Comment: A screenshot of your firewall rules and any relevant object definitions would be helpful. You wouldn't need a static route, as both subnets are connected to the firewall. It already knows how to route between them. I assume the clients on either network point to the sonicwall as their default gateway.

Comment: Yes clients on the 77.x subnet have sonicwall interface X3 ip address (192.168.77.1) as the gateway, and clients on the 22.x subent have sonicwall interface X0 ip address (192.168.22.1) as the gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As boomi has already pointed out, this is no routing issue but a firewall issue. Most firewalls have an implicit `deny all` rule at the end of their policy list, so everything you haven't explicitly permitted is blocked.

I'm not familiar with SonicWall but basically you need to add a firewall rule to allow your guest to access the printer. Something in the line of

`permit from 192.168.77.0/24 to 192.168.22.123/32`

permits any kind of connection from the guest VLAN to the printer.

If you want to limit access to printing only, you'd refine the rule with something like `to TCP port 9100` for the "raw" PDL port or `to TCP port 445` for SMB access, depending on how you're printing.

Comment: Well, that worked, I can ping the printer, but the HP app doesn't see the printer.  This is now an HP problem, not a network problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most vendor tools rely on the printer being within broadcast range - this isn't given with another VLAN and pretty hard to bridge. Most often this can be worked around on the client.

Comment: Hence my question about creating a route or bridge.  Is it possible to create something like a "port forward" from one subnet to the other, so that the printer appears to be on the same subnet even though it physically is not?